# CodePipeline deployment to Beanstalk fails despite IAM properly set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

## Context

This was a CodeStar project initially, and then it grew into something bigger. We reused the Beanstalk application to create the `stage` and `prod` environments and kept the initially-created `dev` environment as-is.

We updated the CodePipeline to deploy to our new environments using "Elastic Beanstalk" as the Provider. (While CodeStar had setup a deployment using CloudFormation for the environment it automatically provisioned in the Beanstalk application.)

## The problem

The deployment fails due to an error which mentions `autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups` as not being authorized to be executed by the CodePipeline's IAM Role.

Here is the whole error message displayed in CodePipeline:

> Insufficient permissions
>
> Deployment failed.
>
> The provided role does not have sufficient permissions: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-xxx-on-cod-ToolChain/yyy
>   is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
>   (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   AccessDenied; Request ID: 905ee6ef-d75d-4cf8-b5f3-e6b16a5f6477)
>
> Service:AmazonAutoScaling, Message:User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-xxx-on-cod-ToolChain/yyy
>   is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
>
> Failed to deploy application.
>
> Service:AmazonAutoScaling, Message:User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-xxx-on-cod-ToolChain/yyy
>   is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups

## IAM

Here is the **CodePipeline Role**'s content (aka `CodeStarWorker-xxx-on-cod-ToolChain`):

[image]

And here is the associated **Permission Boundary** (originally generated by CodeStar, and eventually updated by us to try to get this whole thing to work):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameters",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ssm:ResourceTag/awscodestar:projectArn": "arn:aws:codestar:yyy:xxx:project/xxx-on-cod"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codestar-yyy-xxx/xxx-on-cod/ssh/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awscodestar-remote-access-yyy/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awscodestar-remote-access-signatures-yyy/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/CodeStarWorker-xxx-on-cod-CloudFormation",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:yyy:xxx:secret:xxx"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "codebuild:*",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:*SecurityGroup*",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor14",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:yyy:xxx:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor6",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor5",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
                "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:yyy:xxx:autoScalingGroup:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "sns:Get*",
                "sns:Publish",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "cloudtrail:StartLogging",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "cloudtrail:CreateTrail",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "xray:Put*",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "sns:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:yyy:xxx:stack/awseb-e-mjdwv9ptcz-stack/2d588c80-5284-11ea-a1d4-068f4db663b8",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:yyy:xxx:stack/awseb-e-mjdwv9ptcz-stack/2d588c80-5284-11ea-a1d4-068f4db663b8/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:yyy:xxx:stack/awscodestar-xxx-on-cod-*",
                "arn:aws:codebuild:yyy:xxx:project/xxx-on-cod",
                "arn:aws:codecommit:yyy:xxx:xxx-on-codecommit",
                "arn:aws:codepipeline:yyy:xxx:xxx-on-cod-Pipeline",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:yyy:xxx:*/xxx-on-cod*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codestar-yyy-xxx-xxx-on-cod-pipe",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codestar-yyy-xxx-xxx-on-cod-pipe/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx/resources/environments/e-fp3mwptx9q",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx/resources/environments/e-fp3mwptx9q/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx/resources/environments/e-mjdwv9ptcz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx/resources/environments/e-mjdwv9ptcz/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## Pipeline

[image]

As you can see, we have two CodeBuild because the first one is the one set up by CodeStar, and the second one is the one that slightly modifies the output artefact so that it is in the right format for a direct upload into Beanstalk.

The succeeded deployment is the one from CodeStar (using CloudFormation Provider), the next one is the failed one (using Beanstalk Provider).

#### CodeStar CodeBuild (`buildspec.yml`)

The output artefact is used by the CloudFormation deployment:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
    commands:
      # Upgrade AWS CLI to the latest version
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - mvn clean compile test
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn war:exploded
  post_build:
    commands:
      - cp -r .ebextensions/ target/ROOT/
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template-file template-export.yml
      # Do not remove this statement. This command is required for AWS CodeStar projects.
      # Update the AWS Partition, AWS Region, account ID and project ID in the project ARN on template-configuration.json file so AWS CloudFormation can tag project resources.
      - sed -i.bak 's/\$PARTITION\$/'${PARTITION}'/g;s/\$AWS_REGION\$/'${AWS_REGION}'/g;s/\$ACCOUNT_ID\$/'${ACCOUNT_ID}'/g;s/\$PROJECT_ID\$/'${PROJECT_ID}'/g' template-configuration.json
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - target/ROOT/**/*
    - .ebextensions/**/*
    - 'template-export.yml'
    - 'template-configuration.json'
```

#### Our CodeBuild (`buildspec-two.yml`)

The output artefact is used by the (failing) Beanstalk deployment:

```
# Everything up to that point is the very same as the code from above

artifacts:
  type: zip
  base-directory: 'target/ROOT'
  files:
    - ./**/*
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```

## Conclusion

I've no idea how the deployment could fail since both the Permission Boundary and the base IAM Role mention that `autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups`.

Moreover, the deployment to the CodeStar environment is running fine, yet that particular environment which fails the deployment comes from an exact replicate (in terms of configuration).

Any ideas?

(Moreover, the initial `dev` environment, just as much as the newly-created `stage` environment, don't even have an AutoScalingGroup associated to them... so I have no idea why the deployment is even trying to do that.)

(And I've looked in S3 to make sure both Artefacts being deployed have the same structure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one to troubleshoot, but from what I can see there are a couple of potential issues. One is that the 'DescribeAutoScalingGroups' action does not support a resource-level permission, so it must be an asterisk as the resource, and not the resource arn. You could try just removing the:

```
"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:yyy:xxx:autoScalingGroup:*"
            ]
```

in the permissions boundary, and replace it with

```
"Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
```

and see if that solves the issue.

Second, the 'AWSCodeDeployFullAccess' role does not contain the 'DescribeAutoScalingGroups' action in the policy. You may need to replace and/or add the 'AWSCodeDeployRole' to be able to use that action. That might solve it.

CodeStar projects are pretty locked down when it comes to permissions, so it can get pretty complex expanding the project. Check here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/add-iam-role.html

and here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/adh-policy-examples.html

Comment: I'm now getting this error: `The provided role does not have sufficient permissions to access Elastic Beanstalk: You don't have permission to access an Amazon S3 object. Bucket = 'elasticbeanstalk-yyy-xxx', key = 'resources/environments/e-mjdwv9ptcz/_runtime/_embedded_extensions/yyy/zzz'.` ... yet again, I have the proper IAM for that.

Comment: Also, where did you find out that "the 'DescribeAutoScalingGroups' action does not support a resource-level permission" ?

Comment: The info is in the EC2 autoscaling docs, here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/control-access-using-iam.html

Comment: For posterity: I changed the `autoscaling` Action to have `*`, and abandoned the idea of following the "minimal privileges" thing and added `ec2:*` and `s3:*` as well. The Amazon error messages are lacking precision for me to decide to spend more days on this.